# CSS-sprite menu and jQuery addClass() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created CSS sprite menu based on this tutorial:
http://buildinternet.com/2010/01/how-to-make-a-css-sprite-powered-menu/
Now I'd like to assign .selected class to the 'a' which was clicked as last one. I've added sipmle script:

```
<script>
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
</script>
```

but the class .selected appears only during loading the page. After loading whole page menu item returns to its normal state. Could you help me with this issue? TIA

Have a nice day:)

Comment: Have you tried to put the code in `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`

Comment: Will not clicking `a` take you to different page?

Comment: @Usman is right. You are leaving your page when you click on a link. Solution: Make some extra scripting functionality that will add the "selected"-class to the page you have just loaded.

Comment: Tahnks for your answers, but to be honest - I don't know how to do it. Could you give me some general hints how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking `a` will take you to a different page, so this event is not gonna work for you. To add `selected` class to the current link you have to code like below:

```
<script>
 $(function(){ //short form of $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").each(function(){

       path=window.location;
       path=String(path).split('/')['3']; //if you use absolute URLs then disable this line

       if($(this).attr('href')==path)
       {
          $(this).addClass("selected");
       }
    });
 });
</script>
```

It will add class `selected` to link(s) if it's `href` matches the current URL of the browser.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that, since this is client-side, it won't work if the user has Javascript turned off. Not that it's common, but still worth to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Here's a quick solution using CSS instead of bulky JS :)

First off, your body tags should have classes assigned to them.

```
<body class="products">
```

for example.

Now, in your menu, assign each `<li>` (I'm guessing/hoping you are using a list, you didn't supply any code so I don't know...) with classes as well.

```
<li class="products"><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>
```

for example.

Now, in your CSS, simply do this:

```
body.products ul#menu li.products a { /* Define how the "selected" button should look, here. */ }
```

These CSS rules will then only be "used" when the visitor is on the "selected" page.

This technique is the msot used as it is without a doubt the quickest and very SEO friendly as the code in your main navigation always stays the same across the site.