# CSS sprite Menu with SELECTED state (only CSS)

Tags: css

I have also tried "http://buildinternet.com/2010/01/how-to-make-a-css-sprite-powered-menu/" and Patrik's solution, but it don't works for me.
---> see the this article: [CSS-sprite menu and jQuery addClass() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588430/css-sprite-menu-and-jquery-addclass-method)

I don't want to use JS....

If I click on a menu button, it opens the hyperlink but the button doesn't change to the "selected" state an STAYS in this state until I will click another button.

can you please take a look at my source code and help me to solve my problem?

CSS:

```
/* Stylesheet fuers CSS Sprite Menu */
ul#menu{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; clear:both;}
    #menu li{overflow:hidden; text-indent:-9999px; display:inline; float:right; margin-right:10px;}
        #menu li a{background:url('menu_sprite.gif') no-repeat; width:100%; height:100%; display:block;}


        /* button1 Button */
        #menu li.button1{width:151px; height:18px;}
            #menu li.button1 a{background-position:-5px -5px;}
            #menu li.button1 a:hover{background-position:-161px -5px;}
            #menu li.button1 a.selected{background-position:-317px -5px;}
            body.button1 #menu li.button1 a{background-position:-317px -5px;}

        /* button2 Button */
        #menu li.button2{width:151px; height:18px;}
            #menu li.button2 a{background-position:-5px -28px;}
            #menu li.button2 a:hover{background-position:-161px -28px;}
            #menu li.button2 a.selected{background-position:-317px -28px;}
```

HTML-CODE for the menu:

```
<ul id="menu">

<li class="button1"><a href="../meine_sicht/meine_sicht_lauftext.html" target="lauftext">MEINE SICHT</a></li>
<BR>
```

KINESIOLOGIE

HTML Code in meine_sicht_lauftext.html:

```
<body class="button1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#707173" link="#bd4749" vlink="#bd4749" alink="#bd4749" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
```

Comment: Could you describe the actual problem please.

Comment: uh sorry - I've changed my article now....

Comment: Could you link your site here or represent your problem in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: "it opens the hyperlink but the button doesn't change to the selected state an STAYS in this state until I will click another button" - I'm confused, so does it change to the selected state or not? Which state does it stay in then? Also you shouldn't really be using `<br>` tags after a `<li>` as that's bad practice (the `<li>` element breaks the line for you, if you want to increase the gap use css)

Comment: Look at the solution by My Head Hurts. You expect it to work without actually changing the class of the `li`. Your `.selected` is not a pseudo class like `:hover`, it's **your own class**, so you have to write that behaviour yourself using JavaScript (i.e. when you click on it will get the `selected` class assigned to it). Moreover I would not use framesets, it's 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you have defined a `.selected` style for each of your buttons, but you will have to apply that class style yourself, eg:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="button1">
        <a href="/" class="selected">...</a>
    </li>
    <li class="button2">
        <a href="/">...</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the example HTML above, the `button1` list item will be displayed as specified in your CSS rule:

```
#menu li.button1 a.selected{
    background-position:-317px -5px;
}
```

You can add the class in 3 ways:

1. Have a menu on each page, where the appropriate anchor tag has the `selected` class
2. Add the `selected` class to the anchor using Javascript's onClick event
3. Add the  `selected` class to the appropriate anchor tag using your server-side language since you know which page is being viewed

If you have any questions on how to achieve these, then I will explain in more detail.

**Edit**

Using JQuery, this could be achieved as follows:

```
//wait until DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#menu li a').click(function() {
        $('#menu li a.selected').removeClass( "selected" );
        $(this).addClass( "selected" );
    });

});
```

**JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nC8mK/**

Comment: Thank you. i understand this,but could it be also done with this description I've found here?

Here's a quick solution using CSS instead of bulky JS :)

First off, your body tags should have classes assigned to them.

<body class="products">


Now, in your menu, assign each <li>  with classes as well.

<li class="products"><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>

CSS:
body.products ul#menu li.products a { /* Define how the "selected" button should look, here. */ }

Comment: yes - in this holy forum :o)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588430/css-sprite-menu-and-jquery-addclass-method

scroll down to the answers

Comment: That solution won't work if you're using framesets, it will only work if you reload the whole page after clicking on a menu button.

Comment: thank you MMM, thank you My Head Hurts.

now I'm searching for a solution with Javascript.....I read about JQUERY

*uff* is there a simple way to set the class "selected" for the clicked button and clears the other buttons to normal state?

sorry my questions, but I'm confused already...

Comment: @My Head Hurts: thank you, my code in the header of the menu.html looks like this:
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $('#menu li a').click(function() {
      $('#menu li a.selected').removeClass( "selected" );
      $(this).addClass( "selected" );
      });
  }
 </script>

is that right?

Comment: ok I've changed the code now - and also have uploaded the current version - but theres no effect....please take a look at the actual sourcecode. thank you very much for your helpfulness!!!

Comment: great man - the menu looks now nice - but after implementing this code, suddenly the hyperlinks doesn't work anymore. I've uploaded the current version. THANK YOU! THANKS ALSO TO THIS FORUM! nice people, greatful know how!

Comment: @Ronny No problem don't forget to accept the answer. It will help others in the future and improve your rep.